# weighted job scheduling with more than one intervals for each job

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, scheduling, job-scheduling

I want to schedule jobs with more than one interval for each job. I test some algorithms like MWIS(maximum-weighted-independent-set) but didn't work properly([this pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.353.529&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).
How can I do with this problem?
and can we change the dynamic programing [weighted job scheduling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/weighted-job-scheduling/) for one interval to multiple interval?

Comment: Do the jobs have dependencies?  What restrictions are there on how a job can be divided across intervals?  This is kind of an open-ended question.

Comment: yes for example i have a job with 01:00-02:00 and 05:00-06:00 intervals should do with the weight of 1 and have a job with 01:00-02:00 interval and weight 2 between these two jobs I should choose second job for doing.

Comment: I think that you can turn a job with multiple intervals into multiple jobs with dependencies between them.  Finding the optimal scheduling remains NP-hard though.